# How creating an array with array elements using Visual Basic

Tags: arrays, vba

I want to work with a dynamic array using visual basic and I want that each element of the array will be an individual dynamic array too. How I should proceed? Thanks.

Comment: `myArray = Array(Array(), Array())`

Comment: with that I'll be creating an array with two elements and each element will be a dynamic array, but that 's not what I'm looking for. Thanks anyway...

Comment: In that case you might want to re-work your question to clarify what you want.  I just took it literally.

Answer (score 0):

Read this - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa716275(v=vs.60).aspx

And also this, in case you decide that reDim-ing things is annoying: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.arraylist(v=vs.110).aspx

Essentially though, you want to make an array and fill it with arrays. Then just treat those arrays independently for re-sizing purposes.